# If $X$ is right-continuous and $f$ is locally bounded, then $\int_0^t f(X_s)\:{\rm d}s<\infty$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $E$ be a metric space, $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $E$-valued right-continuous process and $f:E\to[0,\infty)$ be locally bounded and Borel measurable. Is this enough to ensure that $$\int_0^t f(X_s)\:{\rm d}s<\infty\tag1$$ for all $t\ge0$? The question is clearly trivial, when $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ and $f$ are continuous.

Comment: Seems from [here](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~kesmith/nov3notes.pdf) that a locally bounded function on a compact set is bounded. A bounded measurable function has finite lebesgue integral

Comment: @Ilya That's correct, but please note that the assumption is that $f$ is locally bounded; not necessarily $f\circ X$ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example:** $E=\Bbb R$, $X_s=1/(1-s)$ if $0\le s<1$, and $=1$ if $s\ge 1$. This (non-random) path is right continuous, but with $f(x):=|x|$ (certainly locally bounded) the integral $\int_0^2 f(X_s)\,ds$ diverges.

**Fix:** Strengthen the hypothesis on $X$ to "right continuous with left limits".
Suppose that by "locally bounded" you mean that $|f|$ is bounded on each metric ball $B_r(x):=\{y\in E: d(x,y)<r\}$. Fix $t>0$ and $\omega\in\Omega$.  The real-valued function  $s\mapsto d(X_0(\omega),X_s(\omega))$ is then right continuous with left limits for $s\in[0,t]$. As such, it is bounded. Therefore there is a constant $C=C(\omega,t)$ such that $0\le f(X_s(\omega))\le C(t,\omega)$ for all $s\in[0,t]$. The integral $\int_0^t f(X_s(\omega))\,ds$ therefore converges.

Comment: It is even enough to assume that $X$ has left and right limits, since any such path is bounded on a compact interval.